# Make a new object from a multiple record parse.com object

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I need to make a new object out of a multiple record parse.com object in javascript.

This is how I get the entire fetched object:

```js
function(articleID, callback) {
  "use strict";
  var Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
  var query = new Parse.Query(Comment);
  query.descending('createdAt');
  query.equalTo('commentFor', {__type:"Pointer", className:"Article", objectId:articleID});
  query.equalTo('commentApproved', true);
  query.find().then(function(results) {

    callback(results);

  }, function(error){
    callback({error: error});
  });
}
```

Now, the problem is, that this returns (`callback()`) an object which contains some sensitive data, such as the emails of all commenters, so I want to return a new object with, say, just 'name', 'date', and 'comment'. I just don't know how to build an object like this with a multiple record object as the master.

I am making this in node.js, if that helps in any way.

I'd like something along the line of

```
[
    {
        "name": "Robert",
        "date": "2016-01-18T17:59:27.378Z",
        "comment": "Hello World!"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "date": "2016-01-15T16:37:35.226Z",
        "comment": "Bees knees"
    }
]
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work - I don't get the output I'd expect:

```js
var test = function(articleID, callback) {
  "use strict";
  var Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
  var query = new Parse.Query(Comment);
  query.descending('createdAt');
  query.equalTo('commentFor', {__type:"Pointer", className:"Article", objectId:articleID});
  query.equalTo('commentApproved', true);
  query.find().then(function(results) {

    var object = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      object += {
        commentName: results[i].get('commentName'),
        commentWebsite: results[i].get('commentWebsite'),
        commentContent: results[i].get('commentContent'),
        createdAt: results[i].get('createdAt')
      };
    }

    callback(object);

  }, function(error){
    callback({error: error});
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

And then I discovered `query.select()`

This is a case of RTFM! https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints